# How to make XSockets.WebSocket work on HTTPS?

Tags: websocket, webrtc, xsockets.net

First I'd like to apologize if this question has already been answered on other posts.
I'm pretty new in WebSockets and WebRTC and here's my scenario.

I created an MVC4 application in VS 2012 and install the a sample WebRTC project via nuget package manager console (followed the steps here: http://xsockets.net/blog/tutorial-building-a-multivideo-chat-with-webrtc).

This seems to work fine on my local machine. I deployed the code on our https server (running on IIS6) and I changed the connection string to handle the https connection (code below:)

peerBroker = new XSockets.WebSocket("wss://mydomain.com:443/CustomBroker");

I then hit the URL and I got an error that says:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/CustomBroker' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 401

Does anyone have an idea as to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You cant just change the connectionstring to be wss.
Have you configured XSockets to run over wss?

See [XSockets Configuration](http://xsockets.net/docs/4/configuration)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for a super late response... I stopped working on it after some time... Anyway, I'm back and currently working on it... Yes, I've configured XSockets to run over wss.

After I deployed the updated version, I started getting this error: 


WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.com?ctx=5477b0f4-9205-4b73-a4ee-cf8abac6ad00' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: I would recommend you to look at the virtual academy. http://xsockets.net/academy